# SlidingDrawer from left to right issues

Tags: android, slidingdrawer

Dear all I am implementing [ALESSANDRO CRUGNOLA](http://blog.sephiroth.it/2011/03/29/widget-slidingdrawer-top-to-bottom/) custom sliding drawer. I want it to slide to half way across the screen. I did this quite easily for the Right to Left but now I want Left to Right. The problem is that when the drawer 1st opens it slides all the way to the right and then snaps back to the halfway point that I specified. Any ideas on how I can fix this? The code to specify the halfway point is below and the boolean mInvert is true for the Left to Right slider.

```
@Override
protected void onLayout( boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b )
{
    if ( mTracking ) { return; }

    final int width = r - l;
    final int height = b - t;

    final View handle = mHandle;

    int handleWidth = handle.getMeasuredWidth();
    int handleHeight = handle.getMeasuredHeight();

    Log.d( LOG_TAG, "handleHeight: " + handleHeight );

    int handleLeft;
    int handleTop;

    final View content = mContent;
    //mTopOffset = getWidth()/2;
    if ( mVertical ) {
        handleLeft = ( width - handleWidth ) / 2;
        if ( mInvert ) {
            Log.d( LOG_TAG, "content.layout(1)" );
            handleTop = mExpanded ? height - mBottomOffset - handleHeight : mTopOffset;
            content.layout( 0, mTopOffset, content.getMeasuredWidth(), mTopOffset + content.getMeasuredHeight() );
        } else {
            handleTop = mExpanded ? mTopOffset : height - handleHeight + mBottomOffset;
            content.layout( 0, mTopOffset + handleHeight, content.getMeasuredWidth(), mTopOffset + handleHeight + content.getMeasuredHeight() );
        }
    } else {
        handleTop = ( height - handleHeight ) / 2;//centre alings the handle
        if( mInvert ) {
            mBottomOffset = getWidth()/2;//to limit the window sliding half way
            handleLeft = mExpanded ? width - mBottomOffset - handleWidth : mTopOffset;

            content.layout( mTopOffset, 0, mTopOffset + content.getMeasuredWidth(), content.getMeasuredHeight() );
        } else {
            mTopOffset = getWidth()/2;//to limit the window sliding half way
            handleLeft = mExpanded ? mTopOffset : width - handleWidth + mBottomOffset;
            content.layout( mTopOffset + handleWidth, 0, mTopOffset + handleWidth + content.getMeasuredWidth(), content.getMeasuredHeight() );

        }
    }

    handle.layout( handleLeft, handleTop, handleLeft + handleWidth, handleTop + handleHeight );
    mHandleHeight = handle.getHeight();
    mHandleWidth = handle.getWidth();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I would answer this. The key bit was actually in onMeasure() where you have to state that the parent is half width like so
widthSpecSize /=2;
when mInvert is true.

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure( int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec )
{
    int widthSpecMode = MeasureSpec.getMode( widthMeasureSpec );
    int widthSpecSize = MeasureSpec.getSize( widthMeasureSpec );

    int heightSpecMode = MeasureSpec.getMode( heightMeasureSpec );
    int heightSpecSize = MeasureSpec.getSize( heightMeasureSpec );

    if ( widthSpecMode == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED || heightSpecMode == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED ) { throw new RuntimeException(
            "SlidingDrawer cannot have UNSPECIFIED dimensions" ); }

    final View handle = mHandle;
    measureChild( handle, widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec );

    if ( mVertical ) {
        int height = heightSpecSize - handle.getMeasuredHeight() - mTopOffset;
        mContent.measure( MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec( widthSpecSize, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY ), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec( height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY ) );
    } else {
        int width = widthSpecSize - handle.getMeasuredWidth() - mTopOffset;
        if( mInvert ) {
            widthSpecSize /=2;//to limit the sliding halfway parent is told to be halfscreen
            int widthI = widthSpecSize - handle.getMeasuredWidth() - mBottomOffset;
            mContent.measure( MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec( widthI, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY ), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec( heightSpecSize, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY ) );
        }else{
            mContent.measure( MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec( width, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY ), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec( heightSpecSize, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY ) );
        }
    }

    setMeasuredDimension( widthSpecSize, heightSpecSize );
}
```